# How To Display Data From Database In One Text Field

Tags: php, loops, input, fetch

What I am trying to do is display data from A SQL database from one simple text field but what A fetch array is doing is displaying multiply form fields as it's looping those through as a fetch array does

How can I only have one input field and display all data in it?

You don't need my code as this is a general php question but here it is

```
<?php

$fetch_users_on_list = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table  WHERE blocked_by='$username'");
$fetch_users_on_list_rows = $db->num_rows($fetch_users_on_list);

while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_users_on_list)) {

if($fetch_users_on_list_rows>0) {
   $default_selected = selected;
}


$update_form = "
      <div style='position:relative;left:250px;'>
        <text> <a href='' id='post_update_link' style=''> Post A Update </a>  </text> |
        <text> <a href='' id='upload_update_image' style=''> Upload A Image </a></text>
      </div>
      <div>

        <form action='' method='POST'>

        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-2'><img  class='img-circle' width='100%'/></div>
          <div class='col-md-10'>
          <textarea name='post_message' class='form-control' id='feedbox' rows='1' placeholder='What Is Going On?'></textarea>


<select name='_privacy_selection' id='_privacy_selection'>
  <option value='everyone'>Everyone Can See This Post</option>
  <option value='staff_only'>Only Me and Clan Staff Can See This Post</option>
    <option name='certain_users' id='certain_users' value='certain_users' $default_selected>Certain Users</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <text id='block_field' style='display:none;'>dd</text>

            <input type='submit' name='post_message_submit' id='button' class='btn btn-default' value='Publish'><br>             
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<input type='text' name='privacy_data' id='privacy_data' value=''>


<text id='sometext' style='display:none;position:relative;left:250px;''>
  <b>Select A Image To Post As A Update</b><br>

          <textarea name='say_something_update' class='form-control' id='feedbox' rows='3' cols='8' style='width:30%;' placeholder='Say Something About This'></textarea><br>

      <input type='file' class='form-control' id='image_upload' style='width:50%;' name='image'><br>
      <input type='text' name='youtube_upload' id='youtube_upload' style='width:50%;' placeholder='Specify A YouTube Video URL'><br><br>
      <input type='submit' id='button_upload' class='btn btn-default'  name='process_upload' value='Publish' />

      </form>

</text>

<!-- 
    -this is the actual dialog, yes, it is included in your html body, it is just hidden
    -you can set the dialog title via the 'title' tag 
-->
<div id='basicModal' title='Update Is Empty' style='display:none;'>
    This post appears to be empty please write a update or attach a image first before attempting to post
</div>

 <div id='ttt' title='Duplicate Update' style='display:none;'>
  You have already posted this update please wait $time_set minutes before posting again<br>

</div>

  <div id='post_privacy_options' title='Control Who Can See This Post' style='display:none;'>

  <b>Who Can View This Post?</b><br>
  <input type='text' name='add_share_with_control' id='add_share_with_control' placeholder='Leave Blank If You Want Everyone To View This'><br>
  <small>Note: Specify Each User With A Coma </small>
  <br><br>

  <b>Block These People From Viewing This Post</b><br>

  <input type='text' name='block_share_with_control' id='block_share_with_control' placeholder='Leave Blank To Block No One'><br>
  <small>Note: Specify Each User With A Coma, You cannot block clan staff</small><br>
  <input type='submit' name='submit_values' id='submit_values' value='Done'><br>
  <text id='privacy_control_dialog_messages'> </text>

</div>

<!-- include the jquery library -->
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<!-- include the jquery ui library -->
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js'</script>
";
}
?>
```

Comment: i hate the down vote buttons shows how selfish people are to a newly posted thread just saying

Comment: anywya i hope someone can PLEASE help :(

Comment: Can you give an overview of what the code does? It appears to load data from database, and assign a variable the same html for each row returned.

Comment: are you want show all data in one text field or show only specific data

Comment: all that is equal to the specific user i'm making a block list feature so the users stored in that table will always be blocked
with the current code php would just create more boxes and display each data seperatly

Comment: i thought about just using a cookie to store this data but users can easily delete cookies so i try this method first

Comment: Can you clarify the question and simplify the code sample to show the problem?  From you question as it stands, the issue lies with the where clause in the sql query - it is getting all the pages for the given user, you might need to make it more specific to load only one.

Comment: I would but what I want to archive is to display all data in one text field how can i do this?